# Stream Raspberry PI to other Raspberry PIs

Tags: raspberry-pi, stream

I want to stream the screen of one Raspberry PI to multiple other Raspberry PIs (all internal wired network). Is there an easy, maybe even onboard solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read about `ffserver`... and find it is discontinued. You can read about re-broadcasting servers... and find you have to pay. You can read about multicast... and find there are enormous delays and lags.

So I have a simple solution based on **Redis** which is a simple, very light-weight, easy to install, lightning fast, in-memory data-structure server. It can share integers, strings, sets, images, arrays, lists, sets, ordered sets and hashes across all different platforms and has client bindings for C/C++, Python, bash, PHP, Go, Perl...

I run it on a Mac to keep the load off the Raspberry Pis.

This is how my approach works:

- grab the screen on the RasPi continuously with `ffmpeg`
- read the frames, compress them to JPEG
- stuff the frames into Redis
- let clients grab the frames from Redis and display them

---

Here is the code for the Raspberry Pi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2
import redis
import subprocess

# Set height and width of frame, and size in bytes
w, h  = 1920, 1080
bytes = w * h * 3

# IP address of machine where Redis is running
host='192.168.0.8'
port=6379

# Connect to Redis
r = redis.Redis(host,port)

# Formulate our "ffmpeg" command
cmd = [
   'ffmpeg',                # ffmpeg
   '-r', '20',              # 20 fps
   '-f', 'x11grab',         # grab using X11
   '-i', ':0',              # equivalent of DISPLAY=0:0
   '-vf', f'scale={w}x{h}', # make all frames fixed size so we know how many bytes to read
   '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',     # BGR888 like OpenCV prefers
   '-f', 'rawvideo',        # output rawvideo
   'pipe:1'                 # to stdout
]

# Set up JPEG quality outside loop - note it will affect network bandwidth
encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 75]

# Start ffmpeg grabbing the screen
with subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False) as sp:
   while True:
      # Read frame from ffmpeg
      frame = sp.stdout.read(bytes)
      if not frame:
         break

      # Convert the screen into JPEG
      frameNP = np.frombuffer(frame, np.uint8).reshape((h,w,3))
      _, JPG = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frameNP, encode_param)

      # Stuff the frame into Redis
      r.set('frame', JPG.tobytes())
```

---

Here is the view code for clients:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import redis
import cv2
import numpy as np

# IP address where Redis is running
host="192.168.0.8"
port=6379

# Connect to Redis
r = redis.Redis(host,port)

# Grab frames from Redis continually and display locally
while True:
   # Grab frame from Redis
   im = r.get('frame')
   if im:
      # Convert JPEG into Numpy array
      frame = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(im, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
      # Display 
      cv2.imshow("Viewer", frame)
      # Allow a little while for a keypress and to update display
      if cv2.waitKey(50) == ord("q"):
         break
```